# TypeScript: specify callback err, res types properly

Tags: node.js, typescript, callback

So I have this function, which either calls cb with an error or with a result. TypeScript doesn't like `cb(err, null)`:

```js
function foo(cb: (err: Error | null, result: MyType)) {
   try {
     const result = getResultSomehow();
     cb(null, result);
   } catch(err) {
     cb(err, null) // Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type MyType
}
```

Now this makes sense and I can fix it by altering the signature of the function: `function foo(cb: (err: Error | null, result: MyType | null))` But I don't want that because now the callers of this function suddenly have to check if result is not null. But I want them to just check err, and if err is null, then result must have a value (similarly to NodeJS functions such as `fs.readFile`).

How can I express this in TypeScript?

I did check the types for `fs.readFile` and that is typed like my function, the result argument `data` is a `Buffer`, not optional, and not null. But since their implementation is in plain JS I guess they don't run into the TypeScript error that I run into(?)

Comment: Please share reproducable example

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question - the thing is you can't force a caller of `foo` not to access `result` and prevent him/her from thinking that `result` is defined in the case of an error, unless you do `result: MyType | null`. Maybe he/she assumes that even in case of an error, `foo`  might still return a result.

That being said, I get your point and you can get around this by doing the following:

```
function foo(cb: (err: Error | null, result: MyType) => void) {
   try {
     const result = getResultSomehow();
     cb(null, result);
   } catch(err) {
     cb(err, null as any);
   }
}
```

You should, however, document this such that a caller knows that in case of an error `result` will always be `null`.

Comment: Blursed any ! Thanks though